# hide text in table cell(both button and text) when button inside table cell gets focus

Tags: html, css

in my application i have table cell loaded with button and text. now my question is how do i hide text when button receives focus.is that possible to write same text on top of image.

here is my [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/rashmi/FSTMb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can not solve this problem with CSS alone in case of "focus", since the text (you were talking about the "help", right?) is not a child element of your button. I'd suggest to use JS for this or move the text/image inside of the button.

```
<button><span>Help</span></button>
```

Then you could use CSS to hide the text when the button like this:

```
button:focus span { display: none; }
```

But I'm not sure if that still does what you want.

Comment: Btw., since you've tagged your question "html5": The <font> tag (and I believe the <center> tag as well) have been deprecated since HTML 4. Why not handle this with CSS as well?

Comment: @polarblau, hey thanks for your help.if i include <span> inside button, selection rectangle(one which we get when tab key is pressed) includes both text and button. i want only button(inturn image) to be highlighted. hope you got my point.

Comment: This uses td:hover to emulate the effect you wanted (or at least to clear things up) — http://www.jsfiddle.net/Q97Ca/4/ . td:hover won't work everywhere, though. Does this now "behave" like what you had in mind?

Comment: ya this is the way i wanted but is that possible to achieve the same thing using keyevent like .focus

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "keyevent .focus"? What is triggering this event? You could handle a hover with e.g. jQuery like this $('button').hover(function(){ $(this).next('span').hide(); }, function(){ $(this).next('span').show(); }); "focus" would rather be used in the context of an input field in this context. Maybe you could explain a little further what it is that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: in my application no where i would be using mouse events like hover, mouseover, mouseout. as in previous example you gave it makes use of hover i want to replace that with some key board event.